# Regular expression match numbers not starting with string

Tags: regex, regular-language

I came up with a need in a regular expression for finding numbers that do not start with COM. I tried the following expression, but it does not work as expected, and the condition for COM does not work.

```
(?!(COM|СОМ))\d{11,19}
```

https://regex101.com/r/Ap628q/1/

Comment: Use `(?<!COM|\d)\d{11,19}(?!\d)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew or maybe just end with `\b`?

Comment: @Bohemian No, the regex won't find a match in `А23123132323B`  then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a *negative lookbehind* to check if a string is not immediately preceded with some other pattern. Also, since you are matching a range of digits, you should include digit boundaries, `(?<!\d)` and `(?!\d)`, to your regex.

Use

```
(?<!COM|\d)\d{11,19}(?!\d)
(?<!COM)(?<!\d)\d{11,19}(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6hsqB1/1). The latter will work with Python and Boost regex libraries  that require the lookbehind alternatives to match the text of the same length.

**Details**

- `(?<!COM)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is `COM` immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?<!\d)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is as digit immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d{11,19}` - eleven to nineteen digits
- `(?!\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is as digit immediately to the right of the current location.